# Can c++ create array of pointers to different classes dynamically loaded from dll?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Can c++ create array of pointers to different classes dynamically loaded from dll?
ps.without headers with class definations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to have an exported function that instantiates objects of the class. Then you can, of course, put these values into array.